# About Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: relational-database, erd, entity-relationship

My question is about the inventory.Device table in this ERD (I can't attach image, please help refer it from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25548/separate-archive-tables-or-soft-delete-for-inventory-database)

- Why there are lots of fields be named set as **FK2**, does it have
  some special meaning?
- The field **isArchived** is named as **U5,U4,U1**. What does it mean?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FK** means *foreign key*.  For practical purposes this is an indexed field that refers to the primary key of a table to make a relational link.  There will generally be a referential integrity constraint associated with this index.

**U** means *unique*.  This will be a unique index with matching constraint.

The numbers after *FK* and *U* are sequential numbers to indicate which constraint/index the column comprises, or is a part of.  FK2 is the second foreign key, U1,U4,U5 are the first, fourth and fifth unique indexes.  The order of these constraints is arbitrary.  There is nothing special about being the first or second (etc) constraint.

Comment: the Inventory.Device table in the first chat of the link: field DeviceID is set as PK, U1, U2 and U4; field DeviceTypeID is set as FK2, FK6 and U4; field IsTrackedInSAP is set as FK2. field CanNetwork is set as FK2. field CategoryCode is set as FK2 and U1. ==> does it mean DeviceTypeID, isTrackedInSAP, CanNetwork and CategoryCode are composite PK of other table? (due to they are all FK2). but I still don't know why both DeviceID and CategoryCode are U1? and why both DeviceID and DeviceTypeID are U4? or the chart is wrong? many thanks.

Comment: @user3612793 - When multiple columns have the same tag they are part of the same constraint/key.  It is possible to have a composite unique key.  Think for example of a license plate.  The plate number is only unique within the jurisdiction that issued it.